# JQuery pop-up scroller

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for a JQuery pop-up that also lets you scroll through content similar to this: http://www.fivemobile.com/portfolio

Basically, I want to be able to:
- Click on a image thumbnail (or link)
- Get a popup with containing more content related to the thumbnail (image/html/text)
- Ability to scroll to the next set of content (corresponds to the next thumbnail)

Suggestions for JQuery plugins that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

The website you linked to uses [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/). Using colorbox, what you want should be fairly simple to do.